# Connecting to SQL Server throws pyodbc.InterfaceError

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I try to connect to MS-SQL database on the Azure cloud from Python code like bellow.

```
import pyodbc 
connect_str = "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};" + \
    "Server={server},1433;".format(server='tcp:ipaddress.database.windows.net') + \
    "Database={database};".format(database='mydb') + \
    "uid={uid};".format(uid='myuserid') + \
    "pwd={pwd};".format(pwd='secretpswd') + \
    "Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;"
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connect_str)
```

I get error:

> pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17
>   for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'myuserid'. (18456)
>   (SQLDriverConnect)")

I tried removing port number from Server definition in connection string. Also I tried without option Encrypt and TrustServerCertificate. All the time it shows the same error.

I tried to connect with the same credentials using Management Studio and it worked.

Could you specify what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I managed to find out what was wrong.

My password contained some values that weren't escaped properly.

Firstly if value for connection string option contains ';' it should be escaped with curly braces.

So I needed to replace:

`"pwd={pwd};".format(pwd='secretpswd')` -string `pwd=secretpswd`
with

`"pwd={{{pwd}}};".format(pwd='secretpswd')` - string `pwd={secretpswd}`

Also if password contains any of curly braces it should double it. It can be done like

```
pwd = 'password_with_curly_braces_{}'
pwd = pwd.replace('}', '}}').replace('{', '{{')
```

Comment: Thank you!! This was totally the issue for me and I've been digging around the internet for a week with no correct answer. Guess i should have looked harder ;)

Comment: I created this post with intention to help devs as you and me. I spent definitely too much time investigating that and I'm glad that you could reuse my work :)